# Validar diferencia entre 2 fechas con resultado en años, meses y días

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo una función en javascript para validar la diferencia entre 2 fechas que hay en 2 elementos inputs con type = date. El rango a validar debe ser mayor 5 meses mas 2 dias y menor a 10 años.

Con la libreria moment.js he llegado a la siguiente aproximacion que funciona en el caso que la diferencia sea mayor a 5 meses y menor a 10 años. Los dias que me devuelve esta libreria es respecto a toda la diferencia entre las 2 fechas por eso no me sirve

```
function valTiempo() {
   var a = moment(document.getElementById('txtFechaUno').value);
   var b = moment(document.getElementById('txtFechaDos').value);
   var years = a.diff(b, 'year');
   var months = a.diff(b, 'months');
   var days = a.diff(b, 'days');
   if (years >= 10) return false;
   if (years == 0) {
      if (months <=4) return false;
   }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Una posible técnica sería usar una fecha auxiliar que tenga como año el de la primera, pero el mes y día de la segunda, y ahí si calcular la diferencia entre días.

```js
function valTiempo() {
   var a = moment(document.getElementById('txtFechaUno').value);
   var b = moment(document.getElementById('txtFechaDos').value);
   var years = a.diff(b, 'year');
   var months = a.diff(b, 'months');
   var c = moment();
   c.date(b.date());
   c.month(b.month());
   c.year(a.year());
   var duration = moment.duration(a.diff(c));
   var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs(duration.asDays()));
   if (years >= 10) return false;
   if (years === 0) {
      if (months <=4) return false;
   }
   return diffDays;
 }
 
 function dateHandler(e) {
  console.log(valTiempo());
 }
  console.log(valTiempo());
```

```html
<label for="start">Start date:</label>

<input type="date" id="txtFechaUno" name="txtFechaUno"
       value="2018-07-22" onchange="dateHandler(event);">

<label for="start">End date:</label>

<input type="date" id="txtFechaDos" name="txtFechaDos"
       value="2020-07-01" onchange="dateHandler(event);">
       
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```